# where can i see wordpress automatic redirect History

Tags: permalinks, redirect

WordPress Redirecting all the permalink changes automatically.

for example if i change my post permalinks from :

site.com/%postname%

to

site.com/%post_id%/%postname%

wordpress automatically redirects all the old permalinks to new form .

now i have this question , where this redirects are stored ?
are they stored in database or in a file ?

where i can change them ?

Comment: wordpress has build in redirect functionality. to my knowledge, this is not logged nor saved in the database. but you want to look into the function [redirect_canonical](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) i recently had a website that had huge issues with that, so if you want to disable it, add this one to your theme or custom plugin: `remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
`

Comment: I don't want to disable it , but i had many changes in my permalink during the time and i think this could make some problems for my website . so i decided to find this redirects and clear them out .

Comment: nope. not saved. you could hook into the filter to make some adjustments, but other than that it only tries to find something related before sending the user to 404

Comment: Thank you . but I'm wondering how this redirect system is working ! , it could be better if site admin has access to history for further maintenance

Comment: check the function i linked in my first comment. there you can see, how it operates..